# Segmentation fault when using malloc and realloc with arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I'm fairly new to c and I'm trying to understand and grasp malloc. My program takes an integer x input, then loops until x is met while also taking other integer inputs. I then do various calculations. However I'm getting a segmentation fault and I don't understand why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{

    calculations();
}

void calculations()
{

    int i;
    int x;
    int total = 0;
    double squareRoot;
    double overall;

    scanf("%d", &x);

    int* array = malloc(x * sizeof(int));

    if (!array) {
        printf("There isn't enough memory \n");
        return;
    }

    int c = 0;

    while (c < x) {

        scanf("%d", &array[i]);

        total = array[i] * array[i];
        c++;
    }

    squareRoot = sqrt(total);
    array = realloc(array, x * sizeof(int));

    int b = 0;

    while (b < x) {

        overall = array[i] / squareRoot;
        printf("%.3f ", overall);

        b++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a debugger? That would tell you which line triggered the segmentation fault.

Comment: What's with the weird alignment and missing indent?

Comment: In `array = realloc(array, x* sizeof(int));` if you intended to extend - and then index - the memory allocation, it does not give any more memory, being the *same* allocation as the original `array = malloc(x * sizeof(int));`

Comment: Valgrind will help you narrow down memory access errors like this.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry I forgot to post my indented code. I've edited it now.

Comment: BTW `total =`  --> `total +=`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why should it be +=? Surely = is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Do you only need the last item?

Comment: No I need two items.

Comment: @WeatherVane So I don't need to have the realloc in this program?

Comment: Only if you need to extend the array.

Comment: `foo = realloc(foo, somesize);` is *always wrong*. If `realloc` fails then it leads to a memory leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with

```
 scanf("%d", &array[i])
```

where, the value of `i` is indeterminate.

To elaborate, `i` is an uninitialized local variable and unless initialized explicitly, the contents remain indeterminate. Attempt to use that value, in this scenario, would lead to invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Even if you initialize `i`, you never operated on `i`, so all the changes will be overwritten on a fixed index. You got to take care of this case, too.

Solution: Looking at the code, it appears, you may want to use

```
scanf("%d", &array[c]);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks this fixed my issue! I changed all the array[i] to array[c] however when I now run my program I only get 0.000 as my output? Any idea why this is?